# dc barchart, on filter, first already rendered bar does not disappear correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I've been searching a lot in dc.js-related SO questions, but can't find an answer to this problem. 
I have the following barChart in my project. It's a pretty standard definition. In the following gif you can see what happens: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t71A.jpg

When I filter data in another chart, the bars are moving and readjusting correctly, but the first bar of the chart only disappears when the animation is done. I have no idea how to solve this.

Chart definition is currently this:

```
chart
  .margins(this.margin)
  .width(this.width)
  .height(this.height)
  .group(fakeGroup)
  .dimension(dimension)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .y(d3.scale.log().domain([minimum, this.getMax(yValue)])
    .range(this.height, 0)
    .nice()
    .clamp(true)
  )
  .xAxisLabel(this.xAxisLabel)
  .yAxisLabel(this.yAxisLabel)
  .elasticX(true)
  .title((d) => {return d.key + ': ' + d.value;})
  .ordinalColors(this.color)
  .on('renderlet', (chart) => {
    chart.selectAll('g.x text')
      .attr('dx', '-10')
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(-55)');
  })
  .on('filtered', (chart) => {
  });

chart.ordering((d) => -d.value);
chart.yAxis().ticks(15, ",d").tickSize(5, 10);

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  this.calculateSize();
  chart.width(this.width);
  chart.height(this.height);
  chart.transitionDuration(0);
  chart.rescale();
  chart.redraw();
  chart.transitionDuration(750);
});
```

Comment: Clearly it's a bug. Also [filed here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1262), where I suggest trying one of the feature branches for v2.1.

Comment: For anyone finding this, worked with the temporary branch that was set up by @Gordon, so should be added when dc.js 2.1 comes out.